# Making link bold upon clicking it

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

I want to use jquery to have to change my hyperlink to bold upon clicking it and switch it back to normal when clicking another link.

these are the links that I want to click

```
<div id="secondlevel">
            <ul>
                <li><span><a href="NewReleases.aspx?catalogueCode=cat1">New Releases</a></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="BestSellers.aspx">Best Sellers</a></span></li>
            </ul>
```

This is my query which I feel should work but doesn't.

Advice perhaps.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").on("click", function () {
        $(this).siblings("li").css("fontWeight", "normal");
        $(this).css("fontWeight", "bold");
        window.alert("The link was clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "should work but doesn't"? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: WHy you don't use CSS ?, btw, your page refreshes, right? n that case that's why your jQ does not work.

Comment: @roXon, he is changing the css via jquery.

Comment: font-weight not fontWeight

Comment: @smerny you can always change the *style* in CSS

Comment: Wait a sec. When you click these links you are showing, you'll be loading a different web page. If that's the case, you'll need a different solution, **not** the approach you are taking right now.

Is this what's actually happening in your case?

Comment: I'm confident these guys answering know what they're doing, and their answers should technically do what you were asking. The real question is, **do you know what you're doing?** Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I mean, all the answers involving `e.preventDefault()` simply means your hyperlinks no longer do what it's suppose to do, which is to go to a different page. Yet I see you have actual, legit `href` values there. Please clarify on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default action:

```
$("li").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings("li").css("fontWeight", "normal");
    $(this).css("fontWeight", "bold");
    window.alert("The link was clicked");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shQxf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").on("click", function () {
        $(this).siblings("li").find('a').css("font-weight", "normal");
        $(this).find('a').css("font-weight", "bold");
    });
});
```